# jQuery toggle div with link to colorbox (lightbox)

Tags: jquery, toggle, lightbox, colorbox

I have a div that toggles the visibility of the list below it.  Within that main div, I have a link that opens a colorbox (jquery "lightbox" plugin) to add a new item to the list.

Of course, when I click the link, it doesn't do anything but toggle the list (like its parent).  So I added the stopPropagation() to the link.  It does follow the link now, but it opens in the parent window instead of in the colorbox.

How do I fix this? Thank you :)

```
<div class="list">
<div class="listname">
My List Name
<a href="my_link.html" class="colorbox">Add Item</a>
</div>
<div class="items">
My Items
</div>
</div>

$(".listname").toggle(
 function(){
  $(this).siblings(".items").slideDown(100);
  return false;
 },
 function(){
  $(this).siblings(".items").slideUp(100);
  return false;
 }
);

$(".listname a").click(function(e){ e.stopPropagation();  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly without knowing exactly what the lightbox trigger is but have you tried adding

event.preventDefault();

to prevent the following of the link?

```
$(".listname a").click(function(e){ 
    e.stopPropagation();
e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Didn't think the colorbox code was relevant, but it is: $('a.colorbox').colorbox({ opacity:0.7, iframe:true, innerWidth:550, innerHeight:250, scrolling:false });

Comment: If the colorbox is opening a window in the same page then you do need to "kill the link".
Where are you calling the colorbox method?
ie .colorbox();

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have required Jquery Library before Colorbox script

```
<script src="/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript">
<script>
 jQuery('a.colorbox').colorbox();
</script>
```